# How to style diffently item in a flatlist?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Hi everyone i have a problem styling every item present in a flatlist. i find on stackoverflow that you have to use index in the render item but in the render item i have a component that contains all of my items .

What i wanted to reach is this result :

[image]

here is my code in the home component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  Pressable,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Audio, Book} from '../types';
import customData from '../books.json';
import BookBox from '../components/BookBox';
import Menu from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import Glass from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState<Book[]>([]);
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState<Audio[]>([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [selectedAudio, setSelectedAudio] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setBooks(customData);
  }, []);

  const renderBooks = ({item}: {item: Book}) => <BookBox book={item} />;

  return (
    <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} style={styles.scrollContainer}>
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <Menu name={'menu'} size={30} color={'black'} />
        <Text style={styles.textSearch}>All Books</Text>
        <Glass name={'magnifying-glass'} size={30} color={'black'} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.AudioOrEbookContainer}>
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => setSelected(!selected)}
          style={{backgroundColor: selected ? 'white' : 'transparent'}}>
          <View style={styles.btn}>
            <Text>Ebook</Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>

        <Pressable
          style={{backgroundColor: selectedAudio ? 'white' : 'transparent'}}>
          <View style={styles.btn}>
            <Text>Audiobook</Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={books}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id?.toString()}
          renderItem={renderBooks}
          numColumns={2}
        />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

here is my code in BookBox component:

```
import {Text, Image, StyleSheet, View, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {Book} from '../types';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

interface Props {
  book: Book;
}

export default function BookBox({book}: Props) {
  const {
    author,
    country,
    imageLink,
    language,
    link,
    pages,
    title,
    year,
    overview,
    vote,
  } = book;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {imageLink && (
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('SingleBook', {
              title,
              year,
              pages,
              link,
              language,
              imageLink,
              country,
              author,
              overview,
              vote,
            })
          }>
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{
              uri: `${imageLink}`,
            }}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )}
      {!imageLink && <Text>immagine mancante</Text>}

      <View style={styles.wrap}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{author}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

i'm trying to render items with unique style like in the image above.. can you help me? thank you in avance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you need the item index to be chained to your item styles?

Comment: i'm trying to render items with unique style but i don't how to do it ( i tried whit index but it dind't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `numColumns` of `FlatList` cannot help you to achieve the behavior you want. This is because masonry are not supported by this property, in other words, `numColumns` sets the same height for every item at the same line. As a resort to implementing this behavior you can check this lib: https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-masonry-list